# How to execute python scripts in React.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to develop an interface for a simple satellite contest in my college. We have two teams first team developing with python but my team develops with react.js but we have stuck we need to get telemetry data. There is a script for getting them but this script is written in python but I don't have any idea about calling a python script in js. as you can see I'm completely lost can you guys help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: you can't call python script directly from JS in browser.

Depending on what you want to do there may be some solutions. For example you can send network request to server that will call python script and then reply with data retrieved. If you have JS on node server, you can call python script with [child_process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

well, now you can. it is called [pyscript](https://pyscript.net/) and it is a full cpython runtime provided as webasm. but be aware the project is still very alpha.

```
<html lang="en">   
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script> 
  </head>

  <body>
    Hello world! <br>
    This is the current date and time, as computed by Python:
    <py-script> from datetime import datetime now = datetime.now() now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S")
    </py-script>   
  </body>
</html>
```

and there is a [wrapper](https://github.com/Py4Js/PyScript-React) which aims to provide exactly what you asked for.

Comment: wrapper is not available yet.